# How to detect an error while sending a chat using Smack

Tags: java, xmpp, chat, smack

I'm using smack to send a chat message. While testing i figured out that, when the network is unavilable, the API does not throw any exceptions.

my code :

```
Chat chat = connection.getChatManager().createChat(
        "abc@gmail.com", new MessageListener() {

            @Override
            public void processMessage(Chat arg0, Message arg1) {
                System.out.println(arg1.getFrom() + "  says  " + arg1.getBody());

            }
        });
// I Put a break point here and deliberately disable the network.
// But the following line is not throwing the XMPPException

chat.sendMessage("smack says hi.."); /* Send the message¬† */
```

Should i add any listeners to capture the exception?

Comment: Try this: http://xmpp-tutorials.blogspot.com.br/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't get an exception since it is an asynchronous call.  If you want to know if the connection has been dropped, you will have to register a ConnectionListener with the Connection.